# Extract all public keys from blockchain

Tags: bitcoind, public-key, bitcoinj

I want to extract all **public** keys from the blockchain. Those will probably mostly be keys that have been used to sign transactions.

How would I do this?

Comment: This question seems really similar to your other question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37291/all-bitcoin-public-keys-with-non-zero-balance It seems like Nate Eldrige answered the general aspect of your question and linhares answered how to implement it. Is there some aspect that you want clarification on?

Comment: @NickODell Good catch. In fact, the only difference seems to be "all public keys with non-zero balance" and now "all public keys", so I closed it as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think he's looking for anything less than a list of all known pubkeys.

Comment: @ Wizard Of Ozzie indeed